# What are some examples of Classical AI applications?

Tags: applications, symbolic-ai

I believe that Classical AI uses deductive thought processes. For example, given as a set of constraints, deduce a conclusion.

What are some examples of successfully applying Classical AI to real-world problems?

Answer (score 8):

The term *classical AI* refers to the concept of intelligence that was broadly accepted after the [Dartmouth Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_workshop) and basically refers to a kind of intelligence that is strongly symbolic and oriented to logic and language processing. One basic point is the duality **body** vs. **mind**. It's in this period that the mind starts to be compared with computer software.

#### Two classical historical examples of this conception of intelligence

- [**Deep Blue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)), whose aim in life was to be the master of chess, ruling over the (not-so) intelligent mankind
- [**Eliza**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) a computer-based therapist that turned out to [trigger a critic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Weizenbaum) to the classical AI

### Two technical examples of classical AI

- **Expert systems**, which are computer programs that strongly rely on the type of constraints and conclusions that you refer to, [*in order to accomplish feats of apparent intelligence*](https://www.britannica.com/technology/expert-system)
- **Fuzzy logic**, [*which is an extension of multivalued logic*](https://de.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/what-is-fuzzy-logic.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), but with continuous values instead of discrete ones

Note that in all cases the *hardware* (once compared with the *body*) does not play any role: Intelligence is abstract and independent from the material world.